# How to change terminal to use Ctrl + Click to open URL for juno?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, release-juno, click

Currently, just a simple click will open URLs in the browser. It's really annoying because I never wanted to open or download something. Is that possible to change it to `ctrl` + click?